# PHP CMS project management

Tags: php, content-management-system

I want to start a  PHP CMS project and we are  5 -6 ones,  I'm looking for a solution to start this project as professional as can be, tasks can be saved - file storage and duration

Can you suggest any online project management?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion (and this is a VERY subjectve topic) online project management tools still have a way to go... (especially the free, open-source ones)

What are your requirements exactly? Do you need time tracking as well? Or just a project overview?

I've used web-based, open-source solutions such as:

1. DotProject (I wound it very clunky and difficult to navigate, but I haven't tried the latest version...)
2. ClockingIT (I found this to be quite good, a little bit of work was required to configure your project properly but after that it was pretty easy to use)

I've also tried a couple of paid applications:

1. Basecamp. (This is pretty good though if you want time tracking you'll need to pay a bit more)
2. Staction. (They went for a super-simple UI and I think it went a bit too far as I got majorly confused and couldn't work out how to do anything! the interface is very similar to using Twitter)

I've had some experience using desktop applications too such as Microsoft Project (yuk! Especially if you're working on a small project) and OmniPlan (which is my favorite but unfortunately a desktop app only)

At the end of the day picking a project management tool is a very personal endeavor. My advice would be to try a few different ones and see what you like (most web-based solutions offer free trials for 1 month so that's a good way to test things out)

Here's a good list to get started with...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_project_management_software

Comment: thanks man ,  yeah time tracking is prior .

Comment: That should help you narrow the list somewhat...

Clocking IT, Basecamp and Staction (out of the applications I've personally tired) offer that as a feature.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org), very good project management application built in RoR, you've also got [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) which is built in Python. These are self hosted options

You could also have a look at SaaS stuff such as [BasecampHQ](http://basecamphq.com/) or [ActiveCollab](http://www.activecollab.com/)

Comment: i tried to use redmine but i couldn't find a download link

Comment: Here's the download link for Redmine:

http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=1850

I've heard good things about Redmine (haven't had the chance to try it myself though. If you get it working, tell us how it goes for you)

Comment: guys i find this page  and its awesome , wow ! 
http://www.teamworkpm.net

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [Manymoon](https://manymoon.com/) . It's a task managment on line tool, very simple and user friendly and totally free.